# Dial command does not hangup LEGB when LEGA hangsup

Tags: asterisk

I am using Asterisk AMI Dial command to bridge call. The problem is when LEG A ends LEGB remains active for 30 seconds and vice versa. Is it possible to hangup one channel when other channel hangs up.

Answer (score 0):

LegA is main one.

There are no way still stay LEGB when legA was hanguped. LegB will ALWAYS hangup on LegA hangup.

LegA will not hangup if you have next extension. You can use call via Local/ channel to prevent that.

However it is posible nat issue, when BYE message just not reach your softphone/ATA. For troubleshoot that use

```
 asterisk -r
 sip set debug on
```